# turning on 3D acceleration creates login loop

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, ubuntu-14.04, virtualbox

I have a virtual disk image running Ubuntu 14.04 using VirtualBox. The virtual machine feels laggy, so I went into its display settings and enabled 3D acceleration. However, at startup, entering my password causes the screen to turn black (with possibly a few lines of text) and then return to the original login screen. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is in the absence of Unity 3D acceleration in VirtualBox from the box.

1. Once again enter the display settings and disable 3D acceleration
2. You can check the support for 3D acceleration by typing the command in the console

`$ / usr / lib / nux / unity_support_test -p`

```
Not software rendered:    no
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       no
```

3. To enable hardware acceleration, you must run the following commands:

   `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential compizconfig-settings-manager`
4. Install VirtualBox guest additions (previously selecting `Devices -> Install Guest Additions` from the VirtualBox menu)

   `cd /media/`whoami`/VBOXADDITIONS*`
   `sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`
5. add the kernel's graphical module to startup

`sudo bash -c 'echo vboxvideo >> /etc/modules'`

6. To avoid the effect of "missing windows" you need to run `ccsm`, select the `OpenGL` item and clear the `"Framebuffer object"` checkbox. After that, you need to shut down the virtual machine (without this VirtualBox will not let you change the settings of the virtual machine) and enable 3D acceleration (in the virtual machine select Settings, then `Display -> Enable 3D Acceleration`).

In addition, it would be nice to check in the host BIOS if there are hardware virtualization options and enable them (for example SVM support).